# Can any body tell me is significance of NF_STOP in netfilter hook returns?

Tags: netfilter

Can any body tell me is significance of NF_STOP in netfilter hook returns i.e. when can a hook function return NF_STOP?

Comment: NF_STOP is equivalent to NF_ACCEPT. See http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/netfilter/core.c?v=4.6#L307

Answer (score 0):

NF_STOP is similar to NF_STOLEN , only difference is function callback is called on return in case of NF_STOP.